# Оптимизация 2D игры на Unity под Android

Tags: unity3d, unity3d-android

**Первый вопрос**:
Если у меня есть 2000 единиц еды на карте и 40 врагов, которые постоянно обязаны что-то делать (например есть эту еду, чтобы развиваться параллельно с игроком), плюс не плохая такая логика в скриптах, я оптимизировал код, как мог (пожертвовал не особо нужными, но сильно нагружающими стоками кода, закэшировал все ссылки на компоненты, рассчитываю дистанцию теперь только если враг близко), понизил графику до Medium, но всё равно игра выдаёт лишь 30 FPS в среднем. А если к игроку подлетают вражеские планеты (штуки 4) и начинается взаимодействие, так и до всех 15 FPS падает. Более менее я разобрался с тем, чтобы повысить FPS при взаимодействии объектов и теперь я придумал вот что:

Если я стану отключать у всех игровых объектов Sprite Render через `OnBecameVisible/OnBecameInvisible`, то это как-то даст прирост FPS? Ведь код продолжит выполняться и все 40 врагов продолжат летать по карте и развиваться. Но всё таки это 2000 единиц еды хоть не будут нарисованы. Просто я не знаю, нагружает ли Sprite Render CPU или GPU или что он там должен нагружать. Поможет ли мне такое решение?

---

**Второй вопрос**, более критичный:
Когда бот умирает, я с помощью `Instantiate(eatRedDisposable, transformNow, Quaternion.identity);` создаю 7 объектов еды на его месте, когда я её касаюсь, она удаляется с помощью `Destroy(col.gameObject)`. Но.. после 15 минут игры FPS падает просто до 1 кадра в секунду. Профайлер ругается только на скрипт с GUI (это я поправил). Но я уверен, что падение до 1 FPS связано с спавном и удалением еды. Потому что я убрал этот спавн/удаление еды и FPS стабильно держался 25 - 35. Если `Instantiate/Destroy` не могут обеспечить мне нужный результат, то есть ли аналоги? Как можно спавнить еду по другому?

P.s. вариант с имитацией спавна, типа еда где-то уже лежит за пределами карты и как враг умирает, то еда меняет свой Transform на Transform врага - не подходит. Так как врагов много и после смерти каждого должна оставаться еда, и не важно, далеко игрок или близко. Заспавненную еду могут съесть боты или игрок, как прилетит к месту смерти бота.

Игровой процесс
[image: Игровой процесс]

Сцена в редакторе, объекты не выделены
[image: Сцена в редакторе, объекты не выделены]

Сцена в редакторе, объекты выделены
[image: Сцена в редакторе, объекты выделены]

Comment: Если у вас 2000 "еды" с Monobehaviour'ом, то ничего удивительного. В мини профайлере видно, что Render Thread отрабатывает за 0.9ms, что в рази меньше 16.6ms, необходимых для 60fps.

Comment: Добавьте скрин профайлера, сейчас проблем у игры навалом, но с профайлером будут видны все ботлнеки.